# ServiceStack - Cannot get headers from in Typescript client ResponseFilter

Tags: typescript, http-headers, servicestack, fetch-api

I set up a `ServiceStack` application running on `port 5001`

Using the typescript client for ServiceStack (using `typescript-ref`), I generated the `dtos`

I need to intercept the responses because sometimes my server will redirect the client to another page. But I cannot do it with standard XHR redirects, I need to do this with an HTTP interceptor (similar to angular's)

I set up an angular JsonServiceClient

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonServiceClient } from '@servicestack/client';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceClient extends JsonServiceClient {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    super('https://localhost:5001');
    this.responseFilter = res => {
      const navigateTo = res.headers.get('X-Navigate-To');
      if (!navigateTo) {
        return;
      }
      router.navigateByUrl(navigateTo);
    };
  }
}

// client.responseFilter is triggered successfully, but the Response.headers does not contain the headers sent by the service. Only `content-type: application-json`
```

In my service, I add a request header

```
 // ...
 return new HttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent){
    Headers = {{"X-Navigate-To", "/home/whathever"}}
 }
 // ...
```

I can successfully see the header being returned on the browser console

When I inspect the Fetch Response headers, I only see `Content-Type` as headers, and status code is `200`

How can I add a ResponseFilter that will capture the actual GET / POST / PUT / DELETE requests ?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to expose the "X-Navigate-To" header in the cors feature

```
        appHost.LoadPlugin
        (
            new CorsFeature
            (
                allowCredentials: true,
                allowOriginWhitelist: new List<string> {"https://localhost:4200"},
                allowedHeaders: "Content-Type,Authorization",
                exposeHeaders: "X-Navigate-To"
            )
        );
```